# How to deal with lists of lists when the first index represents rows?

Tags: r, list, tibble

How can I convert a list of list, to a DataFrame, where the first "layer" of lists should be rows?

```
myList = list(
    list(name="name1",num=20,dogs=list("dog1")),
    list(name="name2",num=13,dogs = list()),
    list(name="name3",num=5,dogs=list("dog2","dog4"))
)
```

My first idea was to unlist the elements in the "third layer"

```
myUnList = sapply(myList,function(x){y=x;y$dogs = unlist(y$dogs);y})
```

I can create a tibble

```
tibble(myUnList)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
    myUnList
      <list>
1 <list [3]>
2 <list [2]>
3 <list [3]>
```

Note that, if I had `myList[[1]]` to represent the vector of `name`, it would be simple, but I'm having trouble on how to tidy the data presented the other way. I though about using `purrr` to "invert" the order.

Expected result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      names       num       dogs
     <list>    <list>     <list>
1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <list [1]>
2 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <list [0]>
3 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <list [2]>
```

Are there other type of data structure that supports varying length entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time playing around with `purrr`, I got another solution that doesn't requires typing the names (could be troublesome for really large lists).

```
myList %>% transpose %>% simplify_all %>% tbl_df
```

Results in

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   name   num       dogs
  <chr> <dbl>     <list>
1 name1    20 <list [1]>
2 name2    13 <list [0]>
3 name3     5 <list [2]>
```

The `transpose` function from `purrr` makes this type of conversion automatically.

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the list element by using `map` function from the `purrr` package and then create a new tibble using `data_frame`.

library(tidyverse)

```
dat <- data_frame(name = map_chr(myList, "name"),
                  num = map_dbl(myList, "num"),
                  dogs = map(myList, "dogs"))
dat
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#    name    num dogs      
#   <chr> <dbl> <list>    
# 1 name1 20.0  <list [1]>
# 2 name2 13.0  <NULL>    
# 3 name3  5.00 <list [2]>
```

And if you prefer everything to be in list column, replace `map_chr` and `map_dbl` with `map`.

```
dat <- data_frame(name = map(myList, "name"),
                  num = map(myList, "num"),
                  dogs = map(myList, "dogs"))
dat
#   name      num       dogs      
#   <list>    <list>    <list>    
# 1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <list [1]>
# 2 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <NULL>    
# 3 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <list [2]>
```